# MOUSE_OUT action not working?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am aiming for: when you put your mouse over the clip it plays and then stays on the last frame until the mouse is taken off, then the clip should return back to the first frame.

So far this code works that when you put your mouse over, the clip starts then stops on the last frame.

I also want it that even if you take the mouse off before the clip reaches the final frame it will still return to the first frame.

```
stop();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, playMovie); function playMovie(event) { play(); }
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopMovie); function stopMovie(event) { stop(); }

stop();
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the event listener on the stage? In this case, I don't know if `MOUSE_OUT` will ever fire since the mouse can't technically leave the stage (it can only leave the app itself. I cannot remember if that counts as leaving the stage, however). You could also try removing the `MOUSE_OVER` listener within its handler and re-adding within the `MOUSE_OUT` handler

Comment: By listening on the stage,  all objects in your swf (that allow mouse interaction) will trigger those listeners when the mouse moves over/off them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `stop()` in your `stopMovie` function,  use `gotoAndStop(1)` to reset this to the first frame.

You may want to use the `Event.MOUSE_LEAVE` instead of mouse out if you're wanting this to happen when the mouse leaves the SWF entirely.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Still got a small problem. That when the mouse is over it still runs back to the beginning again. I want it to stay on the final frame. any idea?

Comment: in your timeline, add a `stop()` on the last frame

Comment: You are good!!! Thank you.
May you have a quick look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592705/how-to-apply-action-to-mulitple-flash-layers